# How to convert PCM to MP3/AAC in java?

Tags: java, mp3, pcm, aac, m4a

Do anyone know how to convert bytes which are pcm data from recorder to mp3/m4a or AAC, preferably in pure java ? This is intended as a function in server run java program.